# Can we combine the symmetries of two polytopes to create a more symmetric polytope?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, convex-polytopes, symmetry, polytopes

Suppose that there are two combinatorially equivalent (convex) polytopes $P_1,P_2\subset\Bbb R^d$, that is, both with the same face lattice $\mathcal L$.
The symmetry group $\mathrm{Aut}(P_i)\subset\mathrm O(\smash{\Bbb R^d})$ of $P_i$ induces a group $\Sigma_i\subseteq\mathrm{Aut}(\mathcal L)$ of combinatorial symmetries on the face lattice.

Now, we can generate the larger group $\Sigma:=\langle \Sigma_1,\Sigma_2\rangle\subseteq\mathrm{Aut}(\mathcal L)$ of symmetries of $\mathcal L$.

> **Question:** Is there also a realization of $\mathcal L$ as a polytope $P\subset\smash{\Bbb R^d}$ whose symmetry group $\mathrm{Aut}(P)$ induces (at least) $\Sigma$?

As an example, here are two quadrangles, one is vertex-transitive, one is edge-transitive, and they combine to a quadrangle that is vertex- and edge-transitive.

[image]

Comment: Your previous question seems very related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/311877/can-the-graph-of-a-symmetric-polytope-have-more-symmetries-than-the-polytope-its/

Comment: @SamHopkins Please help me if I am missing something, but the new thing in above questios is, that I already know that the symmetries I am asking for can in fact be realized.

Comment: Sure, I'm just saying, you're again asking for a bigger set of symmetries.

Comment: @M.Winter Do you require equality to hold, i.e. must Aut(P) be equal to $\Sigma$, or merely contain $\Sigma$?

Comment: @Adam Indeed, I only require that $\Sigma$ is contained. Thanks for the note.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I guess I really meant this question of yours is related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/308430/can-we-realize-a-graph-as-the-skeleton-of-a-polytope-that-has-the-same-symmetrie